# How are the three phonetically distinct Arabic h's transcribed in English?

Tags: arabic, transliteration

In Arabic we have three types of "h" sounds, as in the following list:

- ح
- خ
- ه

I would like to know, which of these sounds is commonly transcribed as "kh" in English, and how are the other two "h" sounds transcribed, so as to avoid confusion.

Thanks.

Comment: fwiw, these are not aspirated.the difference between aspirated and non-aspirated is the difference between p  in "peter" and p  in "bump it".

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my post to reflect your observation.

Answer (score 4):

Well, we transcribe in IPA and we spell or transliterate in English, more or less. I assume you're asking about conventional letters and not phonetic symbols. 
ح i.e. [ħ] suffers the most, being rendered as <ḥ> except if a publisher can't handle such exotica (not such a problem these days). خ i.e. [χ] is spelled <kh>, and ه i.e. [h] is spelled <h>.

Comment: So you are saying that the ح , which is rendered with IPA ħ, which is not part of the English alphabet, is not transcribed at all. That is terrible! No workarounds?

Comment: @JackMaddington It is transcribed. Note the dot in <ḥ>

Comment: Thanks, but I am using the Android stack exchange current, and cannot see the h with the dot below. What character sry does this belong to. I cannot see it on my keyboard. I don't think English has such a letter. Where did you find it? Could you quote a reference?

Comment: But why not just make life easy and use something which can be written with the English alphabet charters such as "ch" for example for ح, to contrast it with "kh" for خ?

Comment: Let me try inputting it using an html code: &#7717; .

Comment: I'll actually address that in response to your other question. You should be able to at least read the dot on the Android, but I have no idea how you enter odd characters.

Comment: What odd characters? On my Android 4.4..2 KitKat device, I can see neither the h not the combined dot below. I thought the client had full support for Unicode. Can you try it out?

Comment: Might be version-specific. My phone is 5.1.1 and I see these characters. My tablet is coughing up blood so I can't tell about IceCream.

Comment: My tablet is 4.1.2 and cannot handle h-dot but it does have the dedicated characters h-bar and so on – it can't handle zero-width characters, so [ɪ] should be okay and [ɪ́] (small-cap I with accent) probably disappears.

Comment: What is a zero-width character? And why would you need that phonetic "'I' sound with caret", I don't think it occurs in Arabic. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

there are many transliteration schemes. if you want to be scholarly, follow the Encyclopedia of Islam scheme.  informally, I use H for your first example and h for the last. the middle one is not really an "h" sound, I usually go with "kh".

Comment: The kh sound seems to mimic the ch sound in German and Czech, which is why I called it an 'h sound'. BUT then how would you distinguish a kh to make it different from, say, كح or كه?.

Comment: these are completely different sounds. it's kinda hard to demonstrate in writing, but believe me, there's a huge difference.  find  yourself a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

In English writing, often خ becomes "kh" and the others are combined into "h". For example, محمد → Muhammad (with "h" meaning ح), الله → Allah (with "h" meaning ه).

In lossless Arabic transcription, ح is usually written "ħ" (h with bar) or "ḥ" (h with under-dot) to separate it from ه. But this is rare except in textbooks and scholarly works; I've never seen a news article refer to *Muħammad or *Muḥammad.

Lossless transcription also needs to distinguish "kh" خ from "kh" كه . One approach is to spell كه as "k'h" (ALA-LC does this); another is to write خ as "x" (per ISO 233-2) or "ḫ" (h with under-breve). I personally prefer the second of these options. A handwritten apostrophe is too close to the symbols for ayn and hamza (ʿ and ʾ), while ḫ and ḥ tend to look very similar in print; writing the three as "h", "x", and "ħ" makes them much easier to tell apart.

(In lossy transcription, of course, the distinction between the "kh"s can be ignored entirely.)

Comment: If kh is used to translate خ, then how would you transliterate كح or كه in a lossless manner? Thanks.

Comment: Either with an apostrophe separating them (which needs to look distinct from both ayn and hamza), or by using "x" or "ḫ" for خ. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: I have also seen transcriptions with the ta marbuta ة transliterated, and perhaps even transcribed, as h. Is this incorrect? Can you please comment on the ta Marbury as well? Thanks.

Comment: Anyways, good point. Perhaps one should transcribe "x" instead of "kh" for ك. Seems like English is in done bad need of Arabic transcription reforms? With the current form, when one sees a city name, how on Earth can one figure out how to pronounce it correctly. ????????? (Even with the Arabic spelling, one still needs to know what Targa, Keats, and summa to pronounce. How can you know? Maybe Google Translatecan helpwith the pronunciation (and II wish Google Maps had an option to see city names in their original languages).

Comment: If you use an apostrophe, it will be confused with the forward and backwards apostrophes for ع and ء (anyn and hamza).. Perhaps you can add these to your post, mentioning which is which. Thanks.

Comment: Added a note about the ayn and hamza symbols. They aren't quite apostrophes, but they look similar enough that adding a third one is problematic in handwriting.

Comment: And the ta marbuta...is a special problem. My professor mentioned that it was sometimes transcribed as "t", sometimes "a", sometimes "at", sometimes "ah". When it needed to be unambiguous, he just wrote a ta marbuta directly into the transliteration; other alternatives include ẗ and ŧ. Or you can choose "at" or "ah" depending how it's actually pronounced in that word (though that loses some information).

Comment: regarding "ta marbuta": make it a separate question and I'll give all the gory details.